# Better way to write multiple strpos calls

Tags: php, performance, strpos

I've made a simple script that finds all of the outgoing `<a>` tags of a website, and displays them.

To do this first I scrape the sitemap, put those URLs into an array, then loop through the URLs scraping each one individually looking for `<a>` tags, I then run `strpos()` on each found tag see if its got any URLs that I want to ignore.

The script takes about 5 minutes (500 pages scraped) to complete (running locally) and I was wondering if there was a quicker way to handle the needle/haystack search for excluded params. At the moment I'm using

```
//SEES IF URL CONTAINS EXCLUDED PARAM
function find_excluded_url ($match_url) {
    return strpos($match_url, "mydomain.co.uk") ||
        strpos($match_url, "tumblr.com") ||
        strpos($match_url, "nofollow") ||
        strpos($match_url, "/archive") || 
        strpos($match_url, "page/2");
}
```

To then display the result im using

```
if ( find_excluded_url($element) == false ) {
   echo "<a href='$element->href'>" . $element->href . "</a>";
}
```

Is there a more performant way to achieve this?

Sorry if this is a very obvious question, this is the first real thing I've built with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, `strpos` returns `0` if the element is at the beginning of the string and `false` if the element is not in the string.

For PHP `0` and `false` are the same thing, meaning your script will not identify the links that starts with the keywords.

So I would suggest you change your script to this:

```
function find_excluded_url ($match_url) {
    return strpos($match_url, "mydomain.co.uk") !== false ||
         strpos($match_url, "tumblr.com") !== false ||
         strpos($match_url, "nofollow") !== false ||
         strpos($match_url, "/archive") !== false || 
         strpos($match_url, "page/2") !== false;
}
```

Comment: ive just updated my question above to show how im calling the function, does that have the same effect as the way you've written the function ?

Comment: No try to set $match_url to mydomain.co.uk and use your code, if you do not add "!== false" the function will not recognize it as a match, that is the reason why I proposed you add it to your function.

However if you concern is speed remember calling a function add overhead to the code, so I would suggest you do the strpos inline in the if, it will be slightly faster I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if 1 string is in another, you should use one of the following 2:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Warning at strpos: "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."

```php
/**
 * Loops through the array to see if one
 * of the values is inside the $needle
 *
 * @param  string $needle
 * @param  array  $haystack
 * @return bool
 */
function strstr_array($needle, array $haystack)
{
  foreach($haystack as $search) {
    if(strstr($needle, $search)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$haystack = array('my-domain.com', 'sub.my-domain.com');
var_dump(strstr_array('test my-domain.com or something', $haystack));
```

Comment: The question was about performance. The manual clearly states for strstr: "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead."

Answer (score 0):

```
function find_excluded_url($match_url, $excludeList)
{
    foreach($excludeList as $excluded)
    {
        if(stristr($match_url, $excluded) !== FALSE)
        return TRUE;
        else return FALSE;
    }
}

$excludes = array(
                      'mydomain.co.uk'
                    , 'tumblr.com'
                    , 'nofollow'
                    , '/archive'
                    , 'page/2'
                 );

$example1 = 'http://example.mydomain.co.uk/dir/';
$example2 = 'https://not.in/excludes';
var_dump(find_excluded_url($example1, $excludes));
var_dump(find_excluded_url($example2, $excludes));

// output from browser:  bool(true) bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (preg_match('/word/i', $str))
```

Comment: Please always, explain your answer.